# how to capture URL of an image upon clicking and save the image in isolated storage using silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight

I want to capture and save in any container the URL of an image after clicking it from a website then save the image in isolated storage.

Is there anyone who can provide codes for this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll try to use those code to create an application. I need to analyze first the codes because it is for windows phone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download an image, you need to obtain the URI.
As soon as you get it it is pretty straightforward:

```
 public class ServiceImageDownloader
{
    private readonly BitmapImage _downloadedBmpImage = new BitmapImage();

    public ServiceImageDownloader()
    {
        _downloadedBmpImage.ImageOpened += DownloadedBmpImageImageOpened;
        _downloadedBmpImage.ImageFailed += DownloadedBmpImageImageFailed;
        _downloadedBmpImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
    }

    public void DownloadImage(string imageUri)
    {
      _downloadedBmpImage.UriSource = imageUri;
    }

    private void DownloadedBmpImageImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OnImageDownloaded(new WriteableBitmap(_downloadedBmpImage));
        }
        catch
        {
            //manage other classic errors
        }
    }

    private void OnImageDownloaded(WriteableBitmap wbImTemp)
    {
        //here you get your image as a writeableBmp and you can do whatever you wish,
        //as save it in your IS in your example
    }
}
```

Now for the IS I would suggest you to use youre image as a Stream, or as a serializable object. It could be something like that:

```
 public bool WriteImage(string imageName, Stream streamImage)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile store = null;
        Stream stream = null;

        try
        {

            using (store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForSite())
            {                    
                // Open/Create the file for writing
                stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(imageName,
                    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, store);

                streamImage.CopyTo(stream);

                stream.Close();
                streamImage.Close();
            }
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ie)
        {
           //manage error the way you prefer (think especially to quota management)
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.